# Navbar dropdown menu fixed width

Tags: css, navbar

I'm wondering is there an easy way to fix the width on this dropdown menu?

http://jsfiddle.net/s3bA3/3/

I'd like a box effect dropdown list in the same position as where is says "DROPDOWN"

Seems like it shouldn't bee too hard a fix but I'm pretty new to CSS.

Here's the CSS code:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #242424;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
nav li {
    float: left;
}
nav li li {
    clear: both;
}
nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #7ACC01;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
nav li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nav ul li:hover > ul {      
    display: block;  
    position:absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AK7Fb/

Comment: Easy enough to just apply a BG color to it? (sorry for double post didn't notice enter = submit)